# how to track Google analytics dynamically generated usernames in goal conversions

Tags: google-analytics

Currently am working on a site called sharedemos.com

Initially user lands on home page www.sharedemos.com then goes to https://www.sharedemos.com/sign-up

then after signup a subdomain will form for every user like username.sharedemos.com/dashboard/library/

It will generate new username for every user as a subdomain and I want to know how to track this as conversions in goal conversions.

What type of regular expressions I should use while creating a goal.
Please give me step by step explanation.

Comment: OK, firstly you should make sure you have resolved any privacy issues around this: GA is quite explicit that you shouldn't send personally identifiable information. Secondly, you're going to need to make sure that your cookies are being written to the parent domain, or else your tracking will be a mess. Finally, you'll have trouble identifying this with a page view (although I suppose you could check for hostnames that begin with something) and I'd recommend using an event instead.

Comment: Unless your usernames follow a specific pattern there probably will be no regex that matches what you need (the closest would be to match the page path until the first dot, and that would match any kind of subdomain). Plus if you use the url for the goal it will fire once every visit, signup or not.